# Set timer for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set timer-based for loop in JavaScript.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

How I can I repeat this loop every second and show the value of `i` (the counter)?

Comment: Use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` instead of a `for` loop

Comment: Just like others have done it, they've read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers).

Comment: your question perfectly demonstrate how you hate to google!

Comment: [`async` IIFE is the way to go](https://jsfiddle.net/qap5bwfy/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to control your loops wait time you can combine settimeout with recursion

```
var i = 0;
function callMe() {
  var timetowait = 100;
  // some condition and more login
 i++;
 if(i < 20) {
  setTimeout(callMe, timetowait);
 }

}

callMe();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval( function(){
   console.log(counter);
   counter++;
},1000);
```

Comment: How about the limit of 20 ..?

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
function myFunc() { 
 console.log(i);
 i++;
 if(i == 20) {
   clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at -
 specified intervals (in milliseconds).

The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Comment: Things get more interesting, when 20 comes near ..?

Comment: yea you can call the clearInterval when i becomes 20, i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach too:

```
function loop(start, end, delay, fn) {
    if (start > end) return;    

    function step(){
         // callback fn with current iteration and 
         // recursively calls loop
         fn(start);
         loop(start + 1, end, delay, fn);
    }

    setTimeout(step, delay);
}
```

usage :

```
loop(1, 20, 1000, console.log)
```